# Carto Builder map not filtering dynamically

Tags: carto, filter, dynamic, dynamic-layer

I have a Carto Builder map with several layers and widgets in it. I assumed that when filtering the widgets or the time series that the points on the map would also update to show only the filtered data. For my animated layer, the dynamic filtering is working but the static point layers are not. I have the dynamic option selected under Behavior within the Widgets section and each layer is sourced from the same dataset. What can I do in order for the map to update when the data is filtered through the widgets?

https://acabrera0819.carto.com/builder/843b66b8-0490-433c-a560-3f2b2fa3b386/embed

Comment: Could you share the .carto of your map? [This guide](https://carto.com/learn/guides/intro/downloading-carto-maps/) explains how to download it. Then you can upload it as a zip and share it as a link using GDrive or Dropbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason is that your widgets are pointing only to the animated layer and its source is independent from the other layers.

What you should do if several layers share the same data source is:

1. Create one layer from your data source. In a new map this will be
   typically the layer A.
2. Drag and drop the source node in that layer
   A. It's the rectangle that says `A0 Source whatever`.
3. Do that drag and drop more times if you need more layers.

Now you have a map with several layers that come from the same source node. Style them as you wish.

Now, create the widgets that you want to filter all your layers pointing to the source node they all share (A0 in this example). Now, your widgets will behave as you want, filtering every layer.

The important concept here is the source node. The widgets point to a particular source node in the layers configuration. If your layers have different source nodes (A0, B0, C0), the widgets will only filter the node they're pointing to. Even if they are using the same dataset (`SELECT * FROM table`), they are independent in your particular map.

Comment: This worked great, thank you! I was pulling in multiple versions of the same layer thinking that they would link together. The drag and drop from one layer in the map worked great and now everything is officially dynamic. Thanks again!